# YouTube API v3 PHP - Unsubscribe?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

With the YouTube API v3 and PHP you can easily subscribe to a channel.

```
$resourceId = new Google_Service_YouTube_ResourceId();
$resourceId->setChannelId($_GET['id']);
$resourceId->setKind('youtube#user');
$subscriptionSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionSnippet();
$subscriptionSnippet->setResourceId($resourceId);
$subscription = new Google_Service_YouTube_Subscription();
$subscription->setSnippet($subscriptionSnippet);

$subscriptionResponse = $youtube->subscriptions->insert('id,snippet',
    $subscription, array());
```

But how can i unsubscribe a channel? It's not documented

This is the only help for this I found, but it doesn't say how to do it with the PHP API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/delete

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what is the subscription ID. Once you got it you can perform deletion:

```
$youtube->subscriptions->delete($subscription->getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, get a object of subscription with listSubscriptions method.

```
$channelId = "UCXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$list = $youtube->subscriptions->listSubscriptions('snippet', ['mine'=>'true', 'forChannelId'=> $channelId, 'maxResults' => 1]);
```

and you can unsubscribe channel with id.

```
foreach ($list->items as $each) {
  $youtube->subscriptions->delete($each->getId());
}
```